# Correct URL for Google Calendar Quick Add

Tags: google-calendar

If I add something to my calendar using Quick Add on the web application itself I am presented with a choice of calendars on the following edit details page.

If I add using the string `http://www.google.com/calendar/event?ctext=+{query}+&action=TEMPLATE&pprop=HowCreated%3AQUICKA` I am only presented with the one default calendar in the calendar dropdown list.

Does anyone know if I am using an incorrect URL scheme? Is there one which will give me the list of calendars on the edit details page?

Answer (score 2):

Its been 3 years but I went looking for a URL to use to make a custom search in Alfred 3 to quick add a Google Calendar event and found that this URL worked:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/event?ctext=+{query}+&action=TEMPLATE&pprop=HowCreated%3AQUICKA
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

Here’s the original URL with a complex example query (and minor tweaks):

> [https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=template&ctext=**each+fri+9am-2pm+for+2+weeks+test+at+home**](https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=template&ctext=each+fri+9am-2pm+for+2+weeks+test+at+home)

<sub>(Don’t be confused by a small bug: Google Calendar displays yesterday's date as the start date, but doesn’t actually use it, if you don’t alter it.  Instead, it uses the correct one, or the one you selected, if you change it within the dialog.)</sub>

---

As for the orginial question regarding the calendars dropdown list:
It has all my calendars, but it takes a moment to load them: If I click on the dropdown quickly when the page is first displayed, it only displays my default calendar for a second.